# How to get a list of actions belong to a transaction with eosjs?

Tags: eosjs

Given a transaction id, how to get all actions of this transaction?

For example, this transaction `3871d503ec18800861f83851762455491c88e459e0c70d830ed0120134083501` has a inline action that calls another contract, so it has two actions in total.

I tried to use `rpc.history_get_transaction()`:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); // node only; not needed in browsers
const { JsonRpc } = require('eosjs');

const api_endpoint = 'https://eos.infstones.io';
const rpc = new JsonRpc(api_endpoint, { fetch });

(async ()=> {
  const response = await rpc.history_get_transaction(
    '3871d503ec18800861f83851762455491c88e459e0c70d830ed0120134083501',
    91197571,
  );
  console.info(response);
})();
```

The `traces` field in the response is an empty array, while it should be an array with two elements.

I found that `rpc.get_table_rows()` might be another way, but I don't know how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `history/get_transaction` will return the transaction with all the data belonging to it.

You can find inline-traces in the `"traces"`-section of the returned json.

But be aware, the history-plugin has been deprecated so the endpoint is likely to change.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I tried this API at beginning, it can return almost all information about a transaction, but sadly `traces` is not included.